# When to use class object or json string for http request

Tags: json, servlets, https, jackson

Client code is written in C# and Server code is written in java.

Client can send different request. In server, I have only one doPost() to handle all types of request. So i decided to pass the request parameter as Object. But now i'm confused should i need to send the object or json string.

Please suggest me when should i go for json object and json string.

Comment: Provide more details, maybe about the trade-offs you are dealing with.

Comment: Kind advice: include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Because of interoperability you should always convert your frontend objects into a JSON-String before sending them to the server. Especially when frontend and backend differ in their technology stacks, as it is very likely that a plain C# object is not readable by a JAVA backend. At least not without any 3rd party library.